# Add menu bar at the top of the application

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qmenubar

I am trying to add a menu bar at the very top of the application, not "inside" of it where it usually wants to add it.

Quick example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QMenu

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("< Menu Go Here")
        self.resize(400, 200)
        self.centralWidget = QLabel("Hello, World")
        self.centralWidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self._createMenuBar()

    def _createMenuBar(self):
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        menuBar.addMenu(QMenu("&File", self))
        menuBar.addMenu("&Edit")
        menuBar.addMenu("&Help")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Would create something like:

[image]

However I want the menu to be part of the grey line above it (same line as the icon and window title).

Comment: @musicamante wow, good find. That is not straightforward at all, but does answer the question, thank you!

Comment: It's not straightforward because Qt doesn't provide a direct implementation of that feature, which is only available for Windows and through its [Window Presentation Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation). Since Qt is intended to be a cross-platform toolkit, it's not possible to use it, and a custom, complete implementation must be provided.